# djStripe - zero dollar plan - do not ask for credit card, but create customer

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am using Django app djStripe to work integrate Stripe into my Django app to allow users to subscribe to plans and pay using Stripe.

I want to have a zero dollar plan but create a Stripe customer account so in future using can just change subscription from zero to a paid plan, and then they will be asked for their credit card info.

This is acceptable in Stripe and according to Stripe a zero dollar subscription does not ask for credit card though it does create customer. However, djStripe does ask for credit card with a zero dollar plan.

djStripe [readthedocs](http://dj-stripe.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) does hint at custom plans being the solution but I am need help to determine if

a) that is indeed the way and 
b) if yes to a), then how to implement.

I've setup the plan in my app's Settings.py as follows:

```
DJSTRIPE_PLANS = {
    "starter": {
        "stripe_plan_id": "starter",
        "name": "Starter",
        "description": "Starter subscription.",
        "statement_descriptor": "Starter co",
        "price": 0,  # $0
        "currency": "usd",
        "interval": "year",
        "trial_period_days": 0,
        "team_size": 2,
        "image_count": 1000
    }
}
```

I haven't customized any of the standard djStripe subscription process.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No. Just not sending zero dollar plan sign ups to Stripe. Will send them to Stripe if they upgrade to paid plan.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add trail period in the plan, because without a trial period stripe tries to charge the customer for that it requires a credit card info. Subscribe to `customer.subscription.trial_will_end` stripe will send this webhook three days before the trial expires and on that event update trail for customer.